# Is alphanumeric keys recognized in sql and how do I operations on them?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a node js service for SQL database of one of my client. The primary key of table is as follows: 1,2,...9,A,B,....,Y,Z,10,11,....19,1A,1B....

Now I have two primary keys and I want to read all the rows between them. This is not working:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CustomerMaster WHERE CustomerID BETWEEN 0001G AND 0002B
```

The database is in SQL Express. CustomerID is Primary Key for CustomerMaster. It is database of a Point of Sale software which is proprietary so I can't make any changes in database. Is there any way I can read the rows between two Primary keys?

Comment: "This is not working" is usually not very helpful. As you are getting a syntax error, why don't you just tell us instead of having us guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary keys look like strings.  String constants should be delimited by single quotes:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM CustomerMaster
WHERE CustomerID BETWEEN '0001G' AND '0002B'
```

Comment: @rishiag: That surprises me. Actually the dbms should consider '1H' greater than '0002B', as '1H' starts with a '1' and '0002B' only with a zero.

Answer (score 0):

Pad your id with leading zeros and use its right part, thus converting '1G' to '0001G' for instance. Then compare:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM CustomerMaster 
WHERE right('00000' + CustomerID, 5) BETWEEN '0001G' AND '0002B';
```

Comment: padding the data with leading zeros would be better, what you are doing is not sargable and will result in bad performance

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: That's true, but I read the request such that the database is the way it is and cannot be changed (some system writing data and generating those ids).